# Detectar tecla intro en campo de texto

Tags: onkeypress

Me gustaria que al entrar en un campo de texto, este detectara la pulsación de la tecla intro para poder ejecutar una función.

Este es el campo:

```
<input type="text" id = "txtConvBusFch" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Desde Fecha">

$('#txtConvBusFch').keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes? A mi me funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba la opción sin jQuery:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onKeyUp(event) {
    var keycode = event.keyCode;
    if(keycode == '13'){
      alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox'); 
    }
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  [...]
  <input onkeyup="onKeyUp(event)" type="text" id = "txtConvBusFch" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Desde Fecha">
  [...]
</body>
```

}

Answer (score 8):

Según [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7060762/5587982), a veces hay problemas de compatibilidad, porque el código de algunas teclas puede variar, según la versión de navegador.

En ese caso, usar `keyup` parecer ser la mejor opción.

También, se podría obtener el valor a comparar mediante el uso de `keyCode` o `wich`, de este modo:

```
  var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
```

Te dejo dos ejemplos, uno con jQuery y otro con Javascript.

### Con jQuery

Prueba de este modo.

```js
$("#txtConvBusFch").on('keyup', function (e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keycode == 13) {
        alert("Enter!");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id = "txtConvBusFch" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Desde Fecha">
```

---

### Con Javascript puro

```js
var elInput = document.getElementById('txtConvBusFch');
elInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keycode == 13) {
    alert("Enter!");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtConvBusFch" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Desde Fecha">
```

Answer (score 1):

Este código funciona lo que ocurre con ese problema es facil, no es un problema de compatibilidad lo que ocurre es que cuando se ejecuta el script todavía no se a cargado el arbol del DOM, sucede así:
Abres la página.
Se carga el Html, se lée la cabecera (head), se léen los metas y otras etiquetas, se llega al famoso script, el script dice que hay un (algo, puede ser un input o un simple div, lo que sea vamos...) con un identificador ('#txtConvBusFch') y tiene asociado un evento ('keypress') he inmediatamente va a buscarlo al body pero ve que el cuerpo (body) del html aún no se a cargado, lo que hace que haya un error, la etiqueta input no existe.

El intérprete de javascript del navegador sigue leyendo que ese evento buscará saber si la tecla pulsada es la de 'Enter' (tecla 13) y lanzara en caso de que el evento sea el esperado un 'alert' con un mensaje, fin del script.

Ahora se empieza a hacer el arbol del DOM, se crean todos los elementos tipo divs, párrafos, imagenes he INPUT's...
ahora sí existe el input del que hablas y es cuando el script podría afectar al input. ¿Cómo se hace? Hay varias formas.

Principalmente el problema es que no está cargado el DOM antes que el script, esto se soluciona por ejemplo:

1-. Pon la etiqueta script no en la cabecera sino en el final del body, antes lo tenías escrito así (a groso modo):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script></script>
</head>
<body>
<input/>
</body>
</html>
Ahora ponlo así:
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input/>
<script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Verás que funciona perfectamente.

2-. Veo que usas jQuery, para hacer que el script se ejecute siempre cuando el documento esté listo solo tienes que envolverlo con esto y podrás dejarlo en la cabecera y funcionará bien tambien.

```
<script>
$(function(){
//Aquí va tu código.
})
</script>
```

3-. Puedes poner Tu código sin jQuery en la cabecera metido dentro de esto que lo que hará será ejecutar el código dentro de él cuando el DOM esté cargado.

```
window.onload = function ()
{
//Aquí va tu código.
}
```